# Solve for $y_1, y_2, y_3$ using Picards' method of Iteration: $y'=1+y^2$ ; $y'(0)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to find $y_1, y_2,$ and $y_3$ using Picard's method. What I don't understand is why they initially give $y'(0)$ instead of $y(0)$.

$y(0)$ is needed in order to use the method because it goes in front of the integral as so:

$$
y(0) + \int F(t, y(t))\ dt
$$

What am I supposed to do with $y'(0)$?

Comment: it is $y(0)=0.$ With real valued functions $1 + y^2 \geq 1,$ so the condition in your title is impossible

Comment: @WillJagy But that's what written in my book for school...are you suggesting that the book is wrong?

Comment: probably time to ask your classmates and instructor

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I was wrong. It is actually $y(0)=0$ in the book.

See @WillJagy 's comment for further learning.